# AngularJS: pass value from ng-repeat to barchart

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, bar-chart, angular-filters

I am using [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#countby) countBy function to group and count the number of entries for a column. I would like to pass the values from this into a separate bar-chart on the same page. I have tried a number of ways but haven't manage to get it to work.

```
HTML:
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-chart.js/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
</head>
  <body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
      <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
      <div><canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"chart-data="key" chart-labels="value" chart-series="series"></canvas></div>
      <div><li ng-repeat="(key, value) in myData | countBy: 'col_ky'" >Column Key: {{ key }}, Number of Hits: {{ value }}</li></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'chart.js', 'angular.filter']);
app.controller('myController',['$scope', '$http','$filter',function($scope, $http, $filter) {

 $scope.barData = [];
 $scope.labels = [];
 $scope.myData = [{"col_ky":"75421","crt_ts":1501365031000},{"col_ky":"75421","crt_ts":1501124681000},{"col_ky":"75421","crt_ts":1501124688000},{"col_ky":"880610","crt_ts":1501127589000},{"col_ky":"880610","crt_ts":1501127715000},{"col_ky":"891733","crt_ts":1501128075000},{"col_ky":"75421","crt_ts":1501128130000},{"col_ky":"880610","crt_ts":1501128181000},{"col_ky":"75421","crt_ts":1501128192000},{"col_ky":"885110","crt_ts":1501128364000},{"col_ky":"880610","crt_ts":1501128369000},{"col_ky":"326083","crt_ts":1501130957000},{"col_ky":"75421","crt_ts":1501131142000},{"col_ky":"863184","crt_ts":1501131949000}];


}]);
```

If I could pass the **key**and **value** from ng-repeat into the **barData** and **labels** vars in the controller maybe , I could then use barData and labels to populate the bar chart. So how can I do this?

Comment: do you want to make some event? the question is not clear. you can just use the data in the myData variable and show the bar graph

Comment: Hi @NarenMurali .I wish to put the counts of the number of times the column is seen into the bar graph e.g. col_key 75421 hits 6 . I do not wish to put in the raw data from myData.

Comment: I checked your code [ui-grid click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801982/angular-ui-grid-click-event-on-selected-row) this link can be integrated with ui grid you have created and get the value you need, then create a for loop inside the event to loop through myData and count only the rows having the selected data. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry @NarenMurali, I don't think I need an onclickevent(). I need to be able to pass the key, value directly in the html between div's or else pass the key,value to the controller.

Comment: I have now tried to inject the filter directly into the controller , but I have not been able to get this to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the code jsfiddle working, its working fine. The code shows how to call the custom filter function. I hope this is what you are looking for. Also one more thing. The line that does the custom filter is as so

```
$scope.barData = $filter('countBy')($scope.myData, "col_ky");
```

**Jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/p3exg6rw/9/

**Final Output:**
[image]